# AM335x starter kit simulate using qemu

Tags: linux, arm, microcontroller, qemu, microprocessors

I have http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdssk3358, but recently it is not booting up. After pressing reset, the power LEDs don't glow[only come up for a fraction of a second] and the LCD screen shows greyish white display with nothing afterwards).

Meanwhile,
I have made some custom applications to test with the board using Linux. Wanted to know if I can either simulate/emulate the board using qemu emulator.

I did something like this(used the prebuilt kernel image for now which came with the SD card for linux). Gave -M as realview-pb-a8 since this is Cortex A8. Tried several other variants of this command, but stuck with this error. Please suggest an appropriate command to test/simulate the board using an emulator.

```
arm@ubuntu:~/ti-sdk-am335x-evm-05.05.00.00$ qemu-system-arm -M realview-pb-a8 -kernel board-support/prebuilt-images/uImage-am335x-evm.bin -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/nfs init=/sbin/init"
oss: Could not initialize DAC
oss: Failed to open `/dev/dsp'
oss: Reason: No such file or directory
oss: Could not initialize DAC
oss: Failed to open `/dev/dsp'
oss: Reason: No such file or directory
audio: Failed to create voice `lm4549.out'
VNC server running on `127.0.0.1:5900'
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x80008000

R00=00000000 R01=00000769 R02=70000100 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=80008000
PSR=400001d3 -Z-- A svc32
s00=00000000 s01=00000000 d00=0000000000000000
s02=00000000 s03=00000000 d01=0000000000000000
s04=00000000 s05=00000000 d02=0000000000000000
s06=00000000 s07=00000000 d03=0000000000000000
s08=00000000 s09=00000000 d04=0000000000000000
s10=00000000 s11=00000000 d05=0000000000000000
s12=00000000 s13=00000000 d06=0000000000000000
s14=00000000 s15=00000000 d07=0000000000000000
s16=00000000 s17=00000000 d08=0000000000000000
s18=00000000 s19=00000000 d09=0000000000000000
s20=00000000 s21=00000000 d10=0000000000000000
s22=00000000 s23=00000000 d11=0000000000000000
s24=00000000 s25=00000000 d12=0000000000000000
s26=00000000 s27=00000000 d13=0000000000000000
s28=00000000 s29=00000000 d14=0000000000000000
s30=00000000 s31=00000000 d15=0000000000000000
s32=00000000 s33=00000000 d16=0000000000000000
s34=00000000 s35=00000000 d17=0000000000000000
s36=00000000 s37=00000000 d18=0000000000000000
s38=00000000 s39=00000000 d19=0000000000000000
s40=00000000 s41=00000000 d20=0000000000000000
s42=00000000 s43=00000000 d21=0000000000000000
s44=00000000 s45=00000000 d22=0000000000000000
s46=00000000 s47=00000000 d23=0000000000000000
s48=00000000 s49=00000000 d24=0000000000000000
s50=00000000 s51=00000000 d25=0000000000000000
s52=00000000 s53=00000000 d26=0000000000000000
s54=00000000 s55=00000000 d27=0000000000000000
s56=00000000 s57=00000000 d28=0000000000000000
s58=00000000 s59=00000000 d29=0000000000000000
s60=00000000 s61=00000000 d30=0000000000000000
s62=00000000 s63=00000000 d31=0000000000000000
FPSCR: 00000000
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I wanted to test the applications on the device, but since it is not booting up, I am not able to do anything. My aim is to emulate the AM335x device's Linux kernel that came with the SDK, without the actual hardware, including matrix GUI and other apps; so i can build up on top of this.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks and Regards,

Prathamesh

Comment: The ARM Ltd. Cortex-A8 test chip is definitely not a TI AM335x, nor is any of the off-chip stuff on a RealView PB board likely to be identical to anything on TI's dev board. To analogise, would you assume that [Range Rover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Rover_Classic) body panels and other parts are going to fit a [TVR 350](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TVR_350i) just because they have the same basic engine?

Comment: @Notlikethat Thank you for your response. I believed "It is a low-cost development platform based on the ARM® Cortex™-A8 processor", taken from here: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_Starter_Kit#What_is_the_AM335x_Starter_Kit

Can you please suggest me steps to simulate the board using qemu-system-arm or any other ARM simulators. I am not sure if above command is failing because of improper machine parameter or something else.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I would suggest the first step to simulating the board is to _not_ simulate some completely different, incompatible, board - the _CPU core_ is only one tiny (and pretty much irrelevant in this context) aspect of a system. Compare the [RealView PB peripherals and memory map](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0417d/BBAFEDEB.html) to the AM3358 SoC and note that virtually nothing is identical between the two. If you want to run code for an AM3358-based _system_ you need to at very least emulate some AM3358-based system.